# Determine the max count in a pandas Grouped By df and use this as a criteria to return records

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Afternoon All,

I have a large amount of data over a one month period. I would like to:

a. Find the book with the highest number of trades over that months period.

b. Knowing this provide a groupby summary of all the trades done on that book for the month but display it's months trades within each hour of the 24 hour clock.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book = [                            
                                ('trading_book', ['A', 'A','A','A','B','C','C','C']),                            
                                ('rfq_create_date_time', ['2018-09-03 01:06:09', '2018-09-08 01:23:29', 
                                                          '2018-09-15 02:23:29','2018-09-20 03:23:29',
                                                          '2018-09-20 00:23:29','2018-09-25 01:23:29',
                                                          '2018-09-25 02:23:29','2018-09-30 02:23:29',])

                            ]

df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book)
display(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book)

    trading_book    rfq_create_date_time
0              A    2018-09-03 01:06:09
1              A    2018-09-08 01:23:29
2              A    2018-09-15 02:23:29
3              A    2018-09-20 03:23:29
4              B    2018-09-20 00:23:29
5              C    2018-09-25 01:23:29
6              C    2018-09-25 02:23:29
7              C    2018-09-30 02:23:29    

df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['rfq_create_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['rfq_create_date_time'])
df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['Time_in_GMT'] =  df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['rfq_create_date_time'].dt.hour
display(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book)

    trading_book    rfq_create_date_time    Time_in_GMT
0              A    2018-09-03 01:06:09               1
1              A    2018-09-08 01:23:29               1
2              A    2018-09-15 02:23:29               2
3              A    2018-09-20 03:23:29               3
4              B    2018-09-20 00:23:29               0
5              C    2018-09-25 01:23:29               1
6              C    2018-09-25 02:23:29               2
7              C    2018-09-30 02:23:29               2

df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book =  df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book.groupby(['trading_book']).size().reset_index(name='Traded_Away_for_the_Hour').sort_values(['Traded_Away_for_the_Hour'], ascending=False)   
display(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book)

  trading_book  Trades_Bucketted_into_the_Hour_They_Occured
0            A                         4
2            C                         3
1            B                         1

display(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['Traded_Away_for_the_Hour'].max())

4
```

i.e. Book A has the most number of trades in the month

Now return a grouped by result of all trades done on this book (for the month) but display such that trades are bucketed into the hour they were traded.

```
Time_in_GMT Trades_Book_A_Bucketted_into_the_Hour_They_Occured
0                     0
1                     2
2                     1
3                     1
4                     0
.                     0
.                     0
.                     0
24                    0
```

Any help would be appreciated. I figure there is some way to return the criteria in one line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for top book:

```
df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['rfq_create_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['rfq_create_date_time'])
df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['Time_in_GMT'] =  df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['rfq_create_date_time'].dt.hour
```

---

```
df_Highest_Book =  df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book.groupby(['trading_book']).size().idxmax()
#alternative solution
#df_Highest_Book =  df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['trading_book'].value_counts().idxmax()  
print(df_Highest_Book)
A
```

Then compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) `(==)`, aggregate `sum` for count of `True` values and add missing values by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book = (df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['trading_book']
                                      .eq(df_Highest_Book)
                                      .groupby(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['Time_in_GMT'])
                                      .sum()
                                      .astype(int)
                                      .reindex(np.arange(25), fill_value=0)
                                      .to_frame(df_Highest_Book))
```

---

```
print(df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book)
             A
Time_in_GMT   
0            0
1            2
2            1
3            1
4            0
5            0
6            0
7            0
8            0
9            0
10           0
11           0
12           0
13           0
14           0
15           0
16           0
17           0
18           0
19           0
20           0
21           0
22           0
23           0
24           0
```

Comment: Hi @jezral, Thanks. I was hoping to only return the Book with the highest trades in the 24 hour period, so Book A only. Your output is exactly what is needed but only want Book A column returned as it's got the highest total trades in the 24 hours

Comment: @PeterLucas - Yes, so whats happens if next 24H is top book B ? What is expected output?

Comment: If B has more trades in the next 24 hours then only Book B's column would be returned

Comment: @PeterLucas - Is possible change data sample for this situtation with expected output? Because not sure if understand.

Comment: Sure, changing now

Comment: Post updated. So basicaly find the book with most trades, then display all trades on that book across the hours they occured in the month.

Comment: @PeterLucas - Please check edited answer, solution working if only one top value - here book A. Can you check it?

Comment: The results are always skewed to one book so the top value is fine. Checking now

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks again : )

Comment: Hi @jezrael.et al,  If I wanted to perform the above but on the second  largest count, I was thinking: 

Second_Highest_Count = df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['Time_in_GMT'].nlargest(2).iloc[-1]
df_Second_Book = dfData.loc[df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['Time_in_GMT'] == Second_Highest_Count,'trading_book']
df_Second_Book = df_Second_Book.iloc[0]

Comment: But I am getting all zeroes being returned

Comment: @PeterLucas - I think use `df_Second_Highest_Book =  df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['trading_book'].value_counts().index[2]` - but always need second value exist

Comment: perfect, df_Highest_Traded_Away_Book['trading_book'].value_counts().index[1] works